# HTTP service request not closing database connections

Tags: oracle12c

we have multiple source application servers from where request comes to our database (using single db user). but there are two application servers from which request comes but not cleaned up as checked in database, for rest of app servers there are request comes and immediately gets cleaned up. After analyzing from all sources that how request is coming to db, we suspect one of source channel from where it is using web-service (uses HTTP request).

As we understood HTTP protocol is a "stateless" connection gets destroyed once it completes activity . But we suspect somehow it is not closing db connections.

Any help will be helpful.

Comment: depends to many things. your application may have a active thread-pool. which mean depending upon the pool setting the server will always hold specified amount of connections open.

Comment: Is there anything can we find out at API level whether the connection being closed or not.